# How to automatically start pgAdmin 4 in vagrant box

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrant-provision, pgadmin-4

I have a Vagrant box based on ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and installed pgAdmin 4 following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-v1-1-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) (desktop mode).
So I have pgAdmin in a virtual environnement in `/home/vagrant/pgadmin4` and can start it from within the box as follows :

```
source pgadmin4/bin/activate
python pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

What I would like to do now is to have pgAdmin up and running when the VM starts (following `vagrant up`). I added the following in my `Vagrantfile` :

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "pgadmin4_start.sh", run: "always", privileged: false
```

And the shell script is simply :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/vagrant/
source pgadmin4/bin/activate
python pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py &
```

But this does not seem to work (I also tried to add `disown` at the end of the script).

Is there any way I could have pgAdmin running in the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues running the commands with & and I ended up using `nohup` instead

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/vagrant/
source pgadmin4/bin/activate
nohup python pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py &> /vagrant/nohup.out&
```

This way you can also easily check the output of your python command from the `nohup.out` file, in case there is any error.